# Sorting multiple models in one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using Ruby on Rails 5.2.3 and Mongoid 7.0
I need to be able to sort multiple models (Item and Text) in one cotroller.
Now only Item or Text is sorted, it is necessary that Position was set in relation to each other.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def sort
    params[:item].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Item.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
    end
    head :ok
  end
  def admin
    @user_items = @user.user_feed
  end
end
```

admin.html.erb

```
<div id="items" data-url="<%= sort_users_path %>">
  <%= render partial: 'users/user_item', collection: @user_items %>
</div>
```

_user_item.html.erb

```
<% if user_item[:title].present? %>
  <div id="item_<%= user_item[:id] %>">
    <%= user_item[:position] %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if user_item[:text].present? %>
  <div id="item_<%= user_item[:id] %>">
    <%= raw user_item[:position] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

User.rb

```
def user_activity
    activity_items = []

    items.each do |item|
      activity_item = {}
      activity_item[:id] = item.id
      activity_item[:url] = item
      activity_item[:title] = item.title
      activity_item[:position] = item.position
      activity_item[:item_link] = item.url

      activity_items << activity_item
    end

    texts.each do |text|
      activity_item = {}
      activity_item[:id] = text.id
      activity_item[:url] = text
      activity_item[:text] = text.text
      activity_item[:position] = text.position

      activity_items << activity_item
    end

    activity_items.sort_by! { |activity_item| activity_item[:position] }
    activity_items
  end



  def user_feed
    activity_items = user_activity

    activity_items.sort_by! { |activity_item| activity_item[:position] }
    activity_items
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to add `Text.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)`

```
def sort
  params[:item].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Item.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
    Text.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end
  head :ok
end
```